# Wordpress - how to remove br and p tags from all content entered in the Admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

NOTE: Previous questions on this subject only relate to content entered into the editor window. NOT any custom fields in the admin area. This question is specific to removing surplus tags within custom fields. Please read the question fully before marking as a duplicate.

Using Wordpress I know it's pretty simple to remove the `<br/>` and `<p>` tags from the content entered in the editor:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

However, this isn't being applied to markup entered in a 'Types' custom field in a custom post type. There, when I paste content in, it still gets the auto `<p>` and `<br />` tags.

I can work around this temporarily by altering the core `includes/formatting.php` file:

```
function wpautop($pee, $br = 0) {
```

However, this will get overwritten on future Wordpress upgrades. How can I remove auto `<p>` and `<br/>` tags from any content entered in the Wordpress admin area - specifically custom field areas where the remove_filter on the_content has no effect?

Comment: Nope, that is not particular to custom post types.

Comment: Are you using TinyMCE plugin?

Comment: Nope, visual editor is disabled.